# linux: automount internal hard drive during boot?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, fstab

i try to create my own NAS and i need to automount the internal sata disks during boot
i know i could do using fstab but im searching for a more easy/generalized way so its easier to scale with less handwork needed for every hard drive attached (or every mainboard added to the cluster)

so anyone knows how to automount internal disks without using fstab like ubuntu does for usb drives?

im using ubuntu server 9.10
thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are a number of factors involved
>   in 'hotplugging' and HAL is only one
>   of them. When a new device is added,
>   e.g. a USB drive is plugged in, the
>   following occurs (roughly):
>
> ```
> * The kernel becomes aware of a new device and registers it in /sys.
> * Udev creates a device node (e.g. /dev/sdb1), and loads the
> ```
>
> drivers/modules needed.
>       * The HAL daemon is notified by D-Bus and adds the device and what it
>   can find out about it to its database.
>       * The addition of the new device is broadcast by HAL over D-Bus to
>   whatever programs are subscribing,
>   e.g. Thunar, which shows it as an icon
>   in the shortcuts side panel, or
>   Metacity/Nautilus which will add an
>   icon to the desktop.
>       * Another program listening may be a volume manager, such as
>   thunar-volman or AutoFS, configured to
>   automatically create mount points and
>   mount certain types of drives, start
>   Rhythmbox whenever an iPod is
>   connected, etc.

source: http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HAL

Comment: i think i will have a look at autofs, cause i dont have a graphical desktop installed